# Как перейти на новую страницу через файл html в Django?

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт на фреймворке Django, и я сделал, что-то вроде перехода со страницы на страницу через файл. Переходить на новые страницы я умею, только есть проблема.
Когда я перехожу на новую страницу в поле где пишется URL сайта добавляется та новая страница, вот пример:

В данный момент url сайта такой: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/`
и когда я нажимаю на кнопку-ссылку, которая должна меня перебросить допустим на блог. Url меняется на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/Blog/`

А мне нужно чтобы url менялся на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Blog/`
Я свой перевод на другие страницы делаю с помощью views.py render

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Home/home.html')

def articles(request):
    return render(request, 'Blog/list.html')
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'Home'
urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("Blog/", views.articles, name="Articles"),
]
```

Можно ли как-то перейти на страницу, чтобы `Blog/` не добавлялся к `Home/` (не `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/Blog/`, а `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Blog/`)

Comment: Как сама ссылка выглядит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что в главном файле urls у вас назначен путь

```
path('home/', include('Home.urls'))
```

и если в приложении Home, которое вы указали выше пути будут

```
urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("Blog/", views.articles, name="Articles"),
]
```

то django будет строить пути таким образом

```
home/ + "" из path("", views.index, name="index")
home/ + "Blog/" из path("Blog/", views.articles, name="Articles")
```

для того, что бы пути строилсь, так как вы хотите необходимо из `path('home/', include('Home.urls'))` в главном urls убрать `/home` и оставить просто `''`,

а в вашем приложении назначить пути:

```
urlpatterns =[
        path("home/", views.index, name="index"),
        path("Blog/", views.articles, name="Articles"),
    ]
```

но стоит отметить, что для главной страницы index обычно используют url без префиксов `'home'` или других т.е оставляют `''`, что бы адрес был типа `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: я удалил home/ в приложении и главном файле, чтобы осталось только "", и оно работает. Спасибо